# JSONdata parse using beautifulsoup and output errors

Tags: python, json, python-requests

The following errors are produced when I run the following code:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

JSONDATA = requests.request("GET", "https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1")
JSONDATA = JSONDATA.json()

for line in JSONDATA['posts']:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['episodeNumber'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['title'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['audioSource'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['large'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(line['long'])
    print soup.prettify()
```

The following errors are produced (I have tried all sorts of variants on what it suggests re LXML):

- the LXML issue
- an issue about not liking the .mp3 link but this shouldn't be an issue as this link is correct?
- having an issue finding the 'large' thumbnail, but using the equivalent field for the title, audioSource, etc. doesn't produce the same error but looking at the website data it's the right box?

## Output error

```
python ./test2.py
./test2.py:14: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 14 of the file ./test2.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  soup = BeautifulSoup("features=lxml")(line['episodeNumber'])
./test2.py:16: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 16 of the file     ./test2.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  soup = BeautifulSoup(line['title'])
./test2.py:18: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 18 of the file ./test2.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="lxml"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.

  soup = BeautifulSoup(line['audioSource'])
```

/home/leo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py:335:
    UserWarning:
 "https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/dovetail.prxu.org/criminal/85cd4e4d-fa8b-4df2-8a8c-78ad0e800574/Episode_116_190504_audition_mix_neg18_part_1.mp3" looks like a URL. Beautiful Soup is not an HTTP client. You should probably use an HTTP client like requests to get the document behind the URL, and feed that document to Beautiful Soup.
  ' that document to Beautiful Soup.' % decoded_markup
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./test2.py", line 20, in 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(line['large'])
    KeyError: 'large'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to just get the data in the json this will work.

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

JSONDATA = requests.request("GET", "https://thisiscriminal.com/wp-json/criminal/v1/episodes?posts=1000000&page=1")
JSONDATA = JSONDATA.json()

#loads the Json in a dataframe
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(JSONDATA['posts'])
df.to_csv('posts.csv')
```

The lxml issue will be solved by:
    BeautifulSoup(line['episodeNumber'],'lxml')
This is because BeautifulSoup needs an html parser to make a soup object.
if you don't have lxml do.

```
pip install lxml
```

The Second warning is about you passing a url to create the soup object which doens't work since as the warning says, it doesn't know how to download a link.

And lastly your last error is due to the link json not having a key named 'large'

You will need a exception block there.

Comment: many thanks. That seemed to fix the LXML issue. The .mp3 link is okay I think as I'm not expecting python to play or execute the media file, just pass it to the Kodi media centre which will then do that.

As for the image, looking at an online json viewer - the images and description (i.e. large and long) are set back a few more characters than say 'title' is. How would I reference that in the code?

Comment: The large and long is nested in the 'image' dict, so you have to do, line['image']['large'],

Comment: Just another thought re: your export to .CSV suggestion. I got the following error:

File "pandas/_libs/writers.pyx", line 55, in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 30: ordinal not in range(128)

Will this character cause an issue when I'm parsing this same webpage in this manner and with the same dependencies with other projects?

Comment: try df.to_csv('posts.csv',encoding='utf-8'), you're using Python 2?, also if the answer solved your question please mark it so